# How To Convert JSON To GeoJson For Use With Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API to create a cluster of 33,000 Points on the map. First, allow me to provide some background information.

### Background Info:

In [the Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.loadGeoJson), there is a function called  `loadGeoJson()`.

The callback for `loadGeoJson()` converts the JSON object that is returned from the XHR request to an object that is usable by the API. That object looks something like this:

```
(2) [_.Ke, _.Ke]  
0: _.Ke {m: undefined, j: _.Ze, l: {…}, closure_uid_258027441: 237, __e3_: {…}}  
1: _.Ke {m: undefined, j: _.Ze, l: {…}, closure_uid_258027441: 238, __e3_: {…}}  
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This object is designed for use with the API. I can call methods like `features.map()` and `feature.getGeometry().get(0)` using this notation.

---

### Question:

**How do I take a JSON object formatted as GeoJson** like so:

```
{features: Array(33156), type: "FeatureCollection"}
features: Array(33156)
[0 … 9999]
[10000 … 19999]
[20000 … 29999]
[30000 … 33155]
length: 33156
__proto__: Array(0)
type: "FeatureCollection"
__proto__: Object
```

... **and convert it into a Google Maps GeoJson object that can be used by the API** without having to use AJAX?

My object is right here in my code, but it's unusable because I'm not getting the object from an AJAX request? That doesn't make sense.

> **Note:** Using `addGeoJson()` displays all 33,000+ features (Points) on the map without giving me a chance to use that data to create a cluster. That's too slow! It takes ~18 seconds to load (timed with a stopwatch).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a method that converts JSON to a GeoJson object that's "usable" by the API, so I just used the JSON object itself and "mapped" the features into markers.

```
  // Map all Features to Markers
  var markers = geoJson.features.map(function (feature) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[1], lng: feature.geometry.coordinates[0] }
    });
  });
  // Make The Clusterizer
  var clusterizer = new MarkerClusterer(_map, markers,
    { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
  console.log(geoJson);
```

This is ***much*** faster than rendering 33,000 markers on the map.

*(2 seconds compared to 18)*